# newsequentialid constraint on clustered PK

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I have tables that have clustered primary keys of type uniqueidentifier and they are not sequential, so lot of physical ordering happening.

I know that best would be to use composite primary key with combination of clustered int and non clustered uniqueidentifier, but database is already used in production.

Question is how to alter constraints on PK to use NEWSEQUENTIALID() as default value and are clustered primary keys. I assume that i have to drop and recreate constraints. I am not dba so it will be best if you can provide example with syntax.

Comment: Actually, it would be better to simply use an int identity column as a primary key. No reason to include the guid column since it's unique by definition.

Comment: There are reasons on server side that id is used as guid, so i would rather not change that logic

Answer (score 0):

I found answer to my question, i was not able to add constraint which describe clustered PK and also default value for that column. But i am able to do so with two constraints instead.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.FooTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_FooTableId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC 
)

ALTER TABLE dbo.FooTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_FooTableId_Default] DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() for Id
```